# How to convert a python list of tuples to an array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, python, arrays, json, type-conversion

I am trying to make a website using Flask, where I pass in HTML canvas data to a database and then use that data in another route. When I retrieve the data from the database, it's in the form of a list, here's an example of that list with only one element :

```
[(1, 'circle', '{"pencil":[{"startx":346,"starty":105,"endx":346,"endy":105,"thick":2,"color":"#000000"},{"startx":346,"starty":105,"endx":344,"endy":104,"thick":2,"color":"#000000"},{"startx":346,"starty":105,"endx":341,"endy":103,"thick":2,"color":"#000000"},{"startx":346,"starty":105,"endx":338,"endy":103,"thick":2,"color":"#000000"},{"startx":346,"starty":105,"endx":336,"endy":103,"thick":2,"color":"#000000"},{"startx":346,"starty":105,"endx":333,"endy":103,"thick":2,"color":"#000000"},{"startx":346,"starty":105,"endx":330,"endy":103,"thick":2,"color":"#000000"},{"startx":346,"starty":105,"endx":338,"endy":107,"thick":2,"color":"#000000"},{"startx":346,"starty":105,"endx":338,"endy":107,"thick":2,"color":"#000000"},{"startx":346,"starty":105,"endx":336,"endy":107,"thick":2,"color":"#000000"},{"startx":346,"starty":105,"endx":336,"endy":109,"thick":2,"color":"#000000"}],"line":[],"rectangle":[],"circle":[],"eraser":[]}', 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAu4AAAHCCAYAAACwm0waAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAIABJREFUeF7t3W2SI9lVBuDr/vD8gOgmAsLegNkGrB22Ke4KQjEiAAAECBAgQIEBAcbcHCBAgQIAAAQIECCQQ+D/vr4ThKs0KewAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==', '10', '10', '100', '100')]
```

Following several previous answers given in this type of question, I tried the following approach, first I used `json.dumps()`:

**In Flask:**

```
files = json.dumps(files)
return render_template("edit.html", files=files)
```

**In `edit.html`**, I pass it into a function simply as:

```
<button id="show" onclick="loadImages(`{{ files }}`)">View</button>
```

**Finally in `edit.js`,** I try to read it in an array as follows:

```
function loadImages(sources) {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("paint");    
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    console.log(sources);
    
    sources = JSON.parse(sources);
    console.log(typeof(sources)); 
    for(var i = 0; i < sources.length; i++) {
        ctx.drawImage(sources[i][3], sources[i][4], sources[i][5], sources[i][6], sources[i][7]);
    
    }
  }
```

But this returns an error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token p in JSON at position 18
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at loadImages (edit.js:16)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (edit:39)
```

The output of the `console.log(sources)` in the `loadImages` function is :

```
[[1, "circle", "{"pencil":[{"startx":346,"starty":105,"endx":346,"endy":105,"thick":2,"color":"#000000"},{"startx":346,"starty":105,"endx":344,"endy":104,"thick":2,"color":"#000000"},{"startx":346,"starty":105,"endx":341,"endy":103,"thick":2,"color":"#000000"},{"startx":346,"starty":105,"endx":338,"endy":103,"thick":2,"color":"#000000"},{"startx":346,"starty":105,"endx":336,"endy":103,"thick":2,"color":"#000000"},{"startx":346,"starty":105,"endx":333,"endy":103,"thick":2,"color":"#000000"},{"startx":346,"starty":105,"endx":330,"endy":103,"thick":2,"color":"#000000"},{"startx":346,"starty":105,"endx":326,"endy":103,"thick":2,"color":"#000000"},{"startx":346,"starty":105,"endx":326,"endy":103,"thick":2,"color":"#000000"},{"startx":346,"starty":105,"endx":322,"endy":103,"thick":2,"color":"#000000"},{"startx":346,"starty":105,"endx":319,"endy":103,"thick":2,"color":"#000000"},{"startx":346,"starty":105,"endx":317,"endy":103,"thick":2,"color":"#000000"},{"startx":346,"starty":105,"endx":315,"endy":104,"thick":2,"color":"#000000"},{"startx":346,"starty":105,"endx":314,"endy":104,"thick":2,"color":"#000000"},{"startx":346,"starty":105,"endx":312,"endy":104,"thick":2,"color":"#000000"},{"startx":346,"starty":105,"endx":311,"endy":105,"thick":2,"color":"#000000"},{"startx":346,"starty":105,"endx":310,"endy":106,"thick":2,"color":"#000000"},{"startx":346,"starty":105,"endx":308,"endy":106,"thick":2,"color":"#000000"},{"startx":346,"starty":105,"endx":307,"endy":107,"thick":2,"color":"#000000"},{"startx":346,"starty":105,"endx":306,"endy":107,"thick":2,"color":"#000000"},{"startx":346,"starty":105,"endx":304,"endy":109,"thick":2,"color":"#000000"},{"startx":346,"starty":105,"endx":302,"endy":110,"thick":2,"color":"#000000"},{"startx":346,"starty":105,"endx":301,"endy":111,"thick":2,"color":"#000000"},{"startx":346,"starty":105,"endx":336,"endy":107,"thick":2,"color":"#000000"},{"startx":346,"starty":105,"endx":336,"endy":109,"thick":2,"color":"#000000"}],"line":[],"rectangle":[],"circle":[],"eraser":[]}", "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAu4AAAHCCAYAAACwm0waAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAIABJREFUeF7t3W2SI9lVBuDr/vD8gOgmAsLegNkGrB22ARuAgAimDT/G022ItCuH7LRUkkpS3vPxTITDMK5Snvu8N1VvZ6eyfjX8Q4AAAQIECBAgQIBAeIFfhZ/QgAQIECBAgAABAgQIDMXdJiBAgAABAgQIECCQQEBxTxCSEQkQIECAAAECBAgo7vYAAQIECBAgQIAAgQQCinuCkIxIgAABAgQIECBAQHG3BwgQIECAAAECBAgkEFDcE4RkRAIECBAgQIAAAQKKuz1AgAABAgQIECBAIIGA4p4gJCMSIECAAAECBAgQUNztAQIECBAgQIAAAQIJBBT3BCEZkQABAgQIECBAgIDibg8QIECAAAECBAgQSCCguCcIyYgECBAgQIAAAQIEFHd7gAABAgQIECBAgEACAcU9QUhGJECAAAECBAgQIKC42wMECBAgQIAAAQIEEggo7glCMiIBAgQIECBAgAABxd0eIECAAAECBAgQIJBAQHFPEJIRCRAgQIAAAQIECCju9gABAgQIECBAgACBBAKKe4KQjEiAAAECBAgQIEBAcbcHCBAgQIAAAQIECCQQUNwThGREAgQIECBAgAABAoq7PUCAAAECBAgQIEAggYDiniAkIxIgQIAAAQIECBBQ3O0BAgQIECBAgAABAgkEFPcEIRmRAAECBAgQIECAgOJuDxAgQIAAAQIECBBIIKC4JwjJiAQIECBAgAABAgQUd3uAAAECBAgQIECAQAIBxT1BSEYkQIAAAQIECBAgoLjbAwQIECBAgAABAgQSCCjuCUIyIgECBAgQIECAAAHF3R4gQIAAAQIECBAgkEBAcU8QkhEJECBAgAABAgQIKO72AAECBAgQIECAAIEEAop7gpCMSIAAAQIECBAgQEBxtwcIECBAgAABAgQIJBBQ3BOEZEQCBAgQIECAAAECirs9QIAAAQIECBAgQCCBgOKeICQjEiBAgAABAgQIEFDc7QECBAgQIECAAAECCQQU9wQhGZEAAQIECBAgQICA4m4PECBAgAABAgQIEEggoLgnCMmIBAgQIECAAAECBBR3e4AAAQIECBAgQIBAAgHFPUFIRiRAgAABAgQIECCguNsDBAgQIECAAAECBBIIKO4JQjIiAQIECBAgQIAAAcXdHiBAgAABAgQIECCQQEBxTxCSEQkQIECAAAECBAgo7vYAAQIECBAgQIAAgQQCinuCkIxIgAABAgQIECBAQHG3BwgQIECAAAECBAgkEFDcE4RkRAIECBAgQIAAAQKKuz1AgAABAgQIECBAIIGA4p4gJCMSIECAAAECBAgQUNztAQIECBAgQIAAAQIJBBT3BCEZkQABAgQIECBAgIDibg8QIECAAAECBAgQSCCguCcIyYgECBAgQIAAAQIEFHd7gAABAgQIECBAgEACAcU9QUhGJECAAAECBAgQIKC42wMECBAgQIAAAQIEEggo7glCMiIBAgQIECBAgAABxd0eIECAAAECBAgQIJBAQHFPEJIRCRAgQIAAAQIECCju9gABAgQIECBAgACBBAKKe4KQjEiAAAECBAgQIEBAcbcHCBAgQIAAAQIECCQQUNwThGREAgQIECBAgAABAoq7PUCAAAECBAgQIEAggYDiniAkIxIgQIAAAQIECBBQ3O0BAgQIECBAgAABAgkEFPcEIRmRAAECBAgQIECAgOJuDxAgQIAAAQIECBBIIKC4JwjJiAQIECBAgAABAgQUd3uAAAECBAgQIECAQAIBxT1BSEYkQIAAAQIECBAgoLjbAwQIECBAgAABAgQSCCjuCUIyIgECBAgQIECAAAHF3R4gQIAAAQIECBAgkEBAcU8QkhEJECBAgAABAgQIKO72AAECBAgQIECAAIEEAop7gpCMSIAAAQIECBAgQEBxtwcIECBAgAABAgQIJBBQ3BOEZEQCBAgQIECAAAECirs9QIAAAQIECBAgQCCBgOKeICQjEiBAgAABAgQIEFDc7QECBAgQIECAAAECCQQU9wQhGZEAAQIECBAgQICA4m4PECBAgAABAgQIEEggoLgnCMmIBAgQIECAAAECBBR3e4AAAQIECBAgQIBAAgHFPUFIRiRAgAABAgQIECCguNsDBAgQIECAAAECBBIIKO4JQjIiAQIECBAgQIAAAcXdHiBAgAABAgQIECCQQEBxTxCSEQkQIECAAAECBAgo7vYAAQIECBAgQIAAgQQCinuCkIxIgAABAgQIECBAQHG3BwgQ6CLwxzHGke95X8cYH7vgWicBAgQIPF/gyB9iz1+NIxAgQODPAj+OMT4FwfjfMca7ILMYgwABAgQSCyjuicMzOgECJwVeK+1HlOifxxgfdpMtV/vfy4sAAQIECNwggg==", "10", "10", "100", "100"]]
```

I tried multiple approaches to get this done, but this was the closest I could reach to what I want, how do I proceed to correct this?

Comment: strange is that in JavaScript you have `"` before `{"pencil"` - so it gets string `"{"` and variable `pencil` with may gives unexpected token `p` (from word `pencil`) - and this can make all problem. And I don't understand why you have `'` before `{"pencil"` in Python - and this can make all problem. So all prolbem is that you have wrong data in database.

Comment: it seems problem makes template system which try to escape data - try `{{ files|safe }}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found few problems in this code - all with template:

1. template in flask escapes data (to make it safer) so using `{{ file }}` it creates HTML with

   ```
   [[1, &#34;circle&#34;, &#34;{\&#34;pencil\&#34;:[
   ```

   You can see it in browser if you use `Show Page Source` ( `Ctrl+U`).

   It needs `{{ file|safe }}` to create correct HTML

   ```
   [[1, "circle", "{\"pencil\":[
   ```
2. it doesn't need ticks in ``` loadImages( ``...`` ) ```
3. because `files` puts string with `" "` so `loadImage` has to be in `' '`

   ```
   onclick='loadImages({{ files|safe }})'
   ```
4. browser treats text from `files` as normal code so it parses data at loading and it doesn't need `JSON.parse()`
5. to draw image you have to create `Image` and assign data to `.src`

   ```
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = sources[i][3];

        ctx.drawImage(img, ...)
   ```

---

Minimal working code

**EDIT:**

You don't have to use `json.dumps(data)` but `{{ data|tojson }}`

Eventually you can use `{{ data|safe }}` but it will need to change some `" "` into `' '`.

```py
from flask import Flask, request, render_template_string
import json

app = Flask(__name__)

data = [(1, 'circle',
         '{"pencil":[\
             {"startx":346,"starty":105,"endx":346,"endy":105,"thick":2,"color":"#000000"},\
             {"startx":346,"starty":105,"endx":344,"endy":104,"thick":2,"color":"#000000"},\
             {"startx":346,"starty":105,"endx":341,"endy":103,"thick":2,"color":"#000000"},\
             {"startx":346,"starty":105,"endx":338,"endy":103,"thick":2,"color":"#000000"},\
             {"startx":346,"starty":105,"endx":336,"endy":103,"thick":2,"color":"#000000"},\
             {"startx":346,"starty":105,"endx":333,"endy":103,"thick":2,"color":"#000000"},\
             {"startx":346,"starty":105,"endx":330,"endy":103,"thick":2,"color":"#000000"},\
             {"startx":346,"starty":105,"endx":338,"endy":107,"thick":2,"color":"#000000"},\
             {"startx":346,"starty":105,"endx":338,"endy":107,"thick":2,"color":"#000000"},\
             {"startx":346,"starty":105,"endx":336,"endy":107,"thick":2,"color":"#000000"},\
             {"startx":346,"starty":105,"endx":336,"endy":109,"thick":2,"color":"#000000"}],\
          "line":[],"rectangle":[],"circle":[],"eraser":[]\
         }',
         'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAAKCAAAAACoWZBhAAAAMklEQVR4nEXNwQkAMBACwfFI/y2bxwXia8FFUwF1pCCNJTIIwaD04ctsKRyaldI/9i8u1iwOE6FA880AAAAASUVORK5CYII=',
         '10', '10', '10', '10'
)]

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    text = json.dumps(data)
    return render_template_string('''
<script>
function loadImages(sources) {
    console.log(sources);

    var canvas = document.getElementById("paint");    
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    
    for(var i = 0; i < sources.length; i++) {
        var data = sources[i]
        console.log(data[3]);
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = data[3];
        ctx.drawImage(img, data[4], data[5]); //, data[6], data[7]);
    }
}
</script>

<body>
<h1>files</h1>
<pre>{{ files }}</pre>
<h1>files|safe</h1>
<pre>{{ files|safe }}</pre>
<h1>files|tojson</h1>
<pre>{{ files|tojson }}</pre>
<hr>

<canvas id="paint" width="100" height="100"></canvas><br/>

<button id="show" onclick='loadImages({{ files|safe <button id="show" onclick='loadImages({{ files|safe }})'>View files|safe</button>

<button id="show" onclick='loadImages({{ data|tojson }})'>View data|tojson</button>

<button id="show" onclick="loadImages({{ data|safe }})">View data|safe</button>

</body>
''', files=text, data=data)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    #app.debug = True 
    app.run()
```

For your `data:image` I get error `image broken` so I use my small icon 10x10

[image]

but I don't know why but sometimes I have to click button two times to see image.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, it helps a lot. The reason for you getting a broken image because I had to shorten the base64 encoding while posting the question here because it exceeded the maximum character limit for questions. For clicking two times part, I just used a 1 second timeout and a window reload and then it worked fine for me. Thanks again.